# java.lang.NullPointerException JSONObject Array in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I just starting working with the java JSON library (org.json.simple.JSONObject). 
In my code, I needed to make a JSONARRAY of JSONOBJECTS, 
however instead of finding the 3 different objects in my array, I find the the last object duplicated.

The function code:

```js
private void setMesurement(Date[] ts,  Integer[][] time, String mesurementLabel, Object[][] mesurementValue, Integer[][] unit ) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.FRENCH);
        JSONArray measurements = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject series = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray $_time = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray msrVal = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray unitVal = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject msr = new JSONObject();

        for (int i=0; i<ts.length; i++) {
            
            $_time.clear();
            msrVal.clear();
            unitVal.clear();
            
           for (int j=0; j<time[i].length; j++) {               
                $_time.add(time[i][j]);
                msrVal.add(mesurementValue[i][j]);
                unitVal.add(unit[i][j]);
           }

            series.put("$_time", $_time);
            series.put(mesurementLabel, msrVal);
            series.put("unit", unitVal);            
            msr.put("series", series);
            msr.put("ts", dateFormat.format(ts[i]));
            measurements.add(msr);

        }

        this.ppmp.put("measurements", measurements);
        System.out.println("adding measurements: "+measurements+" to ppmp");
    }
```

and this is the duplicated result:

```css
  "measurements":[
    {"series":{
      "heat":[7,8,9],
      "unit":[2,2,2],
      "$_time":[0,16,36]},
     "ts":"2018-04-23T11:30:35.587+0100"},
    
    {"series":{
      "heat":[7,8,9],
      "unit":[2,2,2],
      "$_time":[0,16,36]},
     "ts":"2018-04-23T11:30:35.587+0100"},
    
    {"series":{
      "heat":[7,8,9],
      "unit":[2,2,2],
      "$_time":[0,16,36]},
     "ts":"2018-04-23T11:30:35.587+0100"}
  ]
```

Comment: You should re-initialize the objects for each new object within the JSON. Move `JSONObject series = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray $_time = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray msrVal = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray unitVal = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject msr = new JSONObject();` inside the for-loop

Comment: Are you sure about the title of the question? Where does the nullpointer happen?

Comment: I am so sorry, you are right, I mistake the title of the question, the real current problem is the duplicated output as in the description

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding overwriting objects in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168524/avoiding-overwriting-objects-in-arraylist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating new JSON Objects for each iteration. You only create one at the beginning, set its values, and add it to the list. Then you overwrite the **same** object's values, and **add it to the list again**. In the end, you have added the object to the list three times, and its values will be the ones from the last iteration.

To fix this, change

```
JSONObject series = new JSONObject();
JSONArray $_time = new JSONArray();
JSONArray msrVal = new JSONArray();
JSONArray unitVal = new JSONArray();
JSONObject msr = new JSONObject();

for (int i=0; i<ts.length; i++) {
    $_time.clear();
    msrVal.clear();
    unitVal.clear();
    ...
    measurements.add(msr);
}
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i<ts.length; i++) {
    JSONObject series = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray $_time = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray msrVal = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray unitVal = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject msr = new JSONObject();
    ...
    measurements.add(msr);
}
```

This way, you create a new object for every step and avoid changing the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 
I can't believe that the solution was as simple as that.